# How to send a JSON object(in get method) over Request with Android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, httpconnection

I want to send the following parameter

```
 data={"method": "category", "parameter": {"id":20, "language":"en"}}
```

to a web service 
How can I do this from android for get method? 
i tried but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your JSON is created like this :

```
 try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("method", "category");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject1.put("id", 20);
                jsonObject1.put("language", "en");
                jsonObject.put("parameter",jsonObject1 );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now you can add this in your request with key as **"data"**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("id",20 );
jsonObject.put("language","en");

JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject2.put("method", "category");
jsonObject2.put("parameter", jsonObject.toString());
```